# Output PDF file created by PdfStamper have all forms visible even some of them were hidden in input PDF file

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I am trying to write Java application with iText (Version 5.5.9) to automate process of filling dynamic PDF with some data. Currently I have code which reads data from file and inserts them to XFA data structure. Output PDF file contains new data but the problem is that all hidden forms in input PDF are visible in output file. Explanation about input PDF file (the template): file have about 8 pages and is using XFA to provide dynamic content. Some forms can be visible or hidden depending of selected option (radio buttons, check or combo boxes).

I have to use PdfStamper in append mode, so currently I have this code:

```
m_Reader = new PdfReader(INPDF_PATH);
m_Stamper = new PdfStamper(m_Reader
            , new FileOutputStream(OUTPDF_PATH)
            , '\0'  // the same pdf version as original file
            , true  // append mode - fixing adobe's signature and advanced functions problem
            );

AcroFields form = m_Stamper.getAcroFields();
m_PdfXfaForm = form.getXfa();
m_XfaFormDocument = m_PdfXfaForm.getDomDocument();

// … Reads data form file and insert them to XML structure (using org.w3c.dom API) 

NodeList datasetList = m_XfaFormDocument.getElementsByTagName(TOP_DATA_TAG_NAME);
Node tmp = datasetList.item(0);
m_PdfXfaForm.fillXfaForm(tmp);

m_Stamper.close();
m_Reader.close();
```

Like I wrote above, data are appended but all hidden forms in input PDF are visible in output file. All radio buttons, check and combo boxes have the same value as in the input file. The given form is hidden again when option is reset (changed to other option and changed back to desired one).

I have dumped DOM structure of XFA just after getting from AcroFields (from created PdfStamper object) and after data insertion (opened output file with PdfReader object), the diff shows only inserted data (the inserted data's XML tree structure has been verified with manually (Adobe Reader XI) added rows). So in output file forms attributes remains the same, especially presence=”hidden”.

This is the code I'm using to dumping XFA XML structure:

```
Transformer tf;

try {
    tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    tf.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    tf.transform(new DOMSource(m_XfaFormDocument), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(OUT_FILE_XML_DUMP)));

} catch (Exception e) {}
```

I also tried to use iText 7 and based on [this example](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext7/samples/blob/develop/publications/book/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/samples/book/part2/chapter08/Listing_08_28_XfaMovies.java) I ported my application but the result is the same.

I was searching for similar problems but I could not find any solution and because this is my first attempt to use iText I cannot handle this problem myself, so I'm looking for solution which will fix the visibility forms with presence=”hidden” attribute in output file which was created with PdfStamper.

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: Unfortunately the PDF file on which I am working on is not my and I have no permission to share it. But I could provide some “internal” information for example using [iText Rups](https://github.com/itext/rups).

Comment: That's a pity. I'd have tried to reproduce and analyze the issue if you had shared the PDF.

Comment: Guessing what the problem is without actual file is a dead deal in case of XFA Forms. The only thing I can advice is for you to take a look at various XFA Filling samples using iText and trying them out yourself on other files, thus making sure you are doing everything correctly in your code, like selecting `TOP_DATA_TAG_NAME`.

Comment: Also had similar situation, when using PdfStamper in not append mode, then hiden fields remaind hiden, but when switch to append mode, then hidden fields become visible.